# How to adjust scroll container height to make scrollable content perfectly adjusted

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a container with overflow-y:scroll.
The content is higher than the container height, hence the scrolling.

The question is how to adapt the height of the container automatically, when the container is next to a div that split a wider container div with fixed height.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/K5CjK/4/)

My code is as follows:

```
   <div  ng-repeat="t in p.tabs" 
        class="tabContent" 
        ng-class="currentTab==t.name?'selected':''"
        >
        <div>
            <h2>{{t.displayName}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="vScrollable">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="l in t.description">
                    {{l}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.popover .tabContent {
    border-top: dotted 1px gray;
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.vScrollable {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K5CjK/7/) ?

I've had another go at this and came up with this. It uses the CSS flexbox, and was the best I could do.

Some of the new CSS (I also made a slight change to HTML adding a wrapper):

```
.popover .tabContent > .wrapper {
  display: -moz-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.popover .tabContent > .wrapper div {
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin : 4px;
}
.popover .tabContent > .wrapper .vScrollable {
  -moz-box-flex: 2;
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -ms-flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
}
```

**Edit**: New answer with fiddle

Comment: Well you changed the model to an absolute positioning. What I'm looking for is something that stick to the current position model (context may vary).

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, sorry

Comment: I don't want to have to compute height (as per your top fixed to 30px). I'm looking for an "elastic" solution.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I had another go on this. Check out the new link